# The Correct Way to Organize Tables

Tags: html, semantics

I have this markup

```
<div id="standards">
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Markup</th>
            <th colspan="4">HTML</th>
            <th colspan="4">XHTML</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Version</th>
            <td colspan="3">4.01</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td colspan="3">1.0</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Flavour</th>
            <td>Strict</td>
            <td>Transitional</td>
            <td>Frameset</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>Strict</td>
            <td>Transitional</td>
            <td>Frameset</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Support</th>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

My question is should I leave the first and second "tr" in the "tbody" as it is now, or should I move them to "thead" from the point of view of semantics. The table as can be seen, has 3 headers. What would be the correct way of doing this? Here is the fiddle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsFu2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple `<tr>`'s in `<thead>` according to the w3 documentation for [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/tabular-data.html#the-thead-element) and doing that would fit your table in terms of semantics, so go ahead and move them to the thead.

Answer (score 1):

If this table really has 3 rows of headers (not data), put them in `<thead>`.

`<td>` is for actual data in general.

There's nothing wrong with `<th>` in a table row, it indicates that the cell is header for that particular row.

You're fine the way it is.